# Symfony 2.5 : Class 'project\StoreBundle\Entity\products' does not exist,

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I follow this tutorial : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html. And I have this issue : 
Class 'project\StoreBundle\Entity\products' does not exist

And, I do not know why...

Here the details:

```
#app/AppKernel.php
...
new project\StoreBundle\projectStoreBundle(),
...
```

---

```
#src/project/StoreBundle/Entity/products.php
namespace project\StoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* products
*/
class products
{  
     ....
}
```

---

```
#src/project/listProductsBundle/Controller/listProductsController.php
namespace project\listProductsBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use project\StoreBundle\Entity\products;

class listProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('projectStoreBundle:products');
        ->find("1");
        return $this->render('projectlistProductsBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => "test"));
    }
}
```

---

```
#app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
```

Could you help me to find a solution? Because, I did not find the mistake

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`use project\StoreBundle\Entity\products;`

to

`use project\StoreBundle\Entity\product;`

The same goes for:

`->getRepository('projectStoreBundle:products');`

must become

`->getRepository('projectStoreBundle:product');`

Comment: thanks, but I am sorry for the bad paste, it is "products" everywhere. I have edited the post

Comment: Has changing the class name to 'products' fixed the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help, You have opened my eyes ;). My problem is fixed

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project